# Difference between Reference Mapping and Embedded Mapping

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

What is the difference between `Reference Mapping` and `Embedded Mapping` in `Doctrine MongoDB ODM`?

I just need to implement one to many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded documents are stored within the document itself. Referenced documents are stored elsewhere.

A simplified example of how Referenced docs are stored in the db:

```
//collection one
{
   _id: "one_1"
   many: [
       "many_1",
       "many_2",
       "many_3"
   ]
 }

 //collection many
 {
     _id: "many_1",
     name: "one"
 },
 {
     _id: "many_2",
     name: "two"
 },
 {
     _id: "many_3",
     name: "three"
 }
```

and Embedded documents:

```
//collection one
{
   _id: "one_1"
   many: [
       { _id: "many_1", name: "one"},
       { _id: "many_2", name: "two"},
       { _id: "many_3", name: "three"}
   ]
 }
```

The former is more flexible, the later is way quicker.
The rule of thumb is to go with references if you need to modify sub-documents individually, or if you need many-to-many refs, or if you can reach the 16MB size limit due to huge number of embedded documents in the foreseeable future.